# Reset StackNavigator when change TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I have a problem with stack navigator ... I have two navigations

```
tabNavigator
    -> main
    -> stackNavigator
      -> page 1
      -> page 2
```

So I would like when i am on page 2 and I click on main (tabNavigator) my stacknavigator reset to page 1 ...

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'PageOne'})
  ]
})

class PageOneScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<View><Text> PageOne </Text><Button title="next" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PageTwo')} /></View>);
  }
}

class PageTwoScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<View><Text> PageTwo </Text><Button title="reset" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)} /></View>);
  }
}

class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<Text> Main </Text>);
  }
}

const stackNav = StackNavigator({
  PageOne: {screen: PageOneScreen},
  PageTwo: {screen: PageTwoScreen}
});

const tabNav = TabNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Stack: {screen: stackNav}
});

export default tabNav;
```

But I do not manage

Answer (score 0):

```
Use tabBarOnPress in tabNavigator which is a callback to handle tap events.
From the above code, add the navigationOption used by the Tab Navigator as coded below. Hope this will solve your problem

const tabNav = TabNavigator({
  Main: {screen: MainScreen},
  Stack: {
    screen: stackNav,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => { 
                navigation.dispatch(
                    NavigationActions.navigate({
                        routeName: 'Stack', //which is your route to be reset
                        action: NavigationActions.reset({
                            index: 0,
                            actions: [
                                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'PageOne' }) //which is the default stack to be shown on pressing the tab
                            ]
                        })
                    })
                );
            }        
        })
  }
});
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.